# How to read characters from a serial keyboard on /dev/inputs/eventX (Speed?)

Tags: keyboard, key-mapping, input

I'm trying to read from a second keyboard whose inputs can be read from /dev/inputs/eventX, but I get rubbish and not the character expected.

I'm accessing my target by using Putty. I can connect to my target through serial debug port 115200 or SSH through IP connection.

From that moment I have my terminal where I type `cat /dev/input/eventX` and when typing from my 2nd keyboard a character sush as 'a', 'b' or 'c', all I get is nonsense (multiple bytes) and it's never the same input. I tried changing the read speed but no better results. (9200Bps for instance but still nonsense).

Is there a speed configuration or communication settings to change? How can I get my ASCII characters?

```
root@SANTARO:~ od -x < /dev/input/eventX
0000000     1569    0000    a3ba    0004    0004    0004    0005    0007
0000020     1569    0000    a3c6    0004    0001    0030    0001    0000
0000040     1569    0000    a3ca    0004    0000    0000    0000    0000
0000060     1569    0000    b0ee    0007    0004    0004    0005    0007
0000100     1569    0000    b0f5    0007    0001    0030    0000    0000
0000120     1569    0000    b0f7    0007    0000    0000    0000    0000
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

data read from these special files are structs of type input_event, defined in linux/input.h, and documented in [input/input.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt).